# Class doesn't recognize the attribute

Tags: python, class, oop, object

```
class Hand:

    def __int__(self):
        self.value= 0
        self.ace=False
        self.Cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        hand_comp=""
        for card in self.Cards:
            card_name=card.__str__()
            hand_comp+= " " + card_name

            return 'The card has %s' %(hand_comp)

    def card_add(self, card):
        '''Add another card to the hand'''
        self.Cards.append(card)
```

Every time i run this, i get an error saying "Object 'Hand' has no attributes 'Cards' . How can i rectify this?

Comment: The initialisation method is `__init__`, not `__int__`.

Comment: Note that you can build the string of cards for ``__str__`` in one go: `handcomp = " ".join(str(card) for card in self.Cards)`. This also avoids the unneeded leading space.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It helped a lot. It was a silly mistake! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong keyword for initializing class
It should be **init** not **int**.

```
def __init__(self):
```